# Find a function which has same integrals as another function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

For domain $[-x^o,x^o]$, I have to find a function $g(x)$  which is equivalent to a given function $f(x)$ in the following sense.

$\int_{-x^o}^{x^o}xf(x)=\int_{-x^o}^{x^o}xg(x)$

$\int_{-x^o}^{x^o}sin(x)f(x)=\int_{-x^o}^{x^o}sin(x)g(x)$

.
.

$\int_{-x^o}^{x^o}h(x)f(x)=\int_{-x^o}^{x^o}h(x)g(x)$

Basically, $g(x)$ is such that n (finite) number of weighted integrals of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal. I am assuming $g(x)$ to have a form such that the equality conditions reduce to a system of linear equations, but I am not able to guarantee that they will have a solution for arbitrary $f$ (integration is always defined). Is there a way to guarantee that or find which space of function will satisfy the equations?

Comment: If you're using Lebesgue integration it suffices for g to be equal to f _almost everywhere_

Comment: An expression of the form $\int_{-x}^x xf(x)$ does not make sense at all. Is $x$ a fixed number? If so, you cannot make it a variable.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, yes the limits are constant.

Comment: f=g is a solution, but I want a simpler $g$ with may be nice properties, irrespective of what $f$ looks like.

Comment: My first thought would be to try something like integration by parts to simplify the integrals.

Comment: Thanks. I know what h(x) typically will be. I will see what integration by parts leads to.